# Select2 - Set val IF selected option == "Apple"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 drop down and would like to know the best way to SET a VALUE if the OPTION selected == " Apple" for instance.

Here is my Select2

```
<select id="fruit" title="fruit" name="fruit"
                                      class="form-control select2-single">
                                  <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                                  <option value="">Apple</option>
                                  <option value="">Lemon</option>
                              </select>
```

What I'd like to achieve is:

If Option "Apple" is selected, SET Value to THISVARIABLE (I get responses from an AJAX Post and would like to dynamically set the Value

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your JS code snippet that demonstrates your best attempt to resolve your question, and then explain at what point in that code you aren't getting the result you expect.  So, in other words, what problem are you encountering when you attempt to set the value?

Comment: I ended up with Dynamically adding NEW options on my AJAX Success .. 

I see thousands of questions being asked here asking for advice, all full of answers and code examples yet users don't involve a bit of code in their question. When it comes to me, my past two questions have constantly received down votes. Appauling.

Comment: I can't speak for your other questions, but this particular question reads like a request for us to write the code for you. It's expected you've done [a lot of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and one common reason why questions get downvoted is because they don't reflect much research effort.  In fact, the tooltip on the downvote arrow says "the question doesn't show any research effort".  So you might consider that....Show us what you've tried, explain why it didn't work, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small example might give you something to study.

The first select is like your AJAX, and it sets a variable. It then uses that variable to set the value of a second drop-down.

Note:
To set the value of a Select/dropdown, set the value of the Select element to be the value of the desired option. Thus, every option should have a "value".

```js
let theVar;

const leSelect = document.querySelector('#fruit')
leSelect.addEventListener('change', handle_sel_change);

function handle_sel_change(e){
   const leComp = document.querySelector('#computer');
   theVar = leSelect.value;

   leComp.style.display = 'block';
   leComp.value = theVar;
}
```

```css
body{display:flex;}
#computer {display: none; margin-left:20px; }
```

```html
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="epple">Apple</option>
    <option value="remon">Lemon</option>
</select>

<select id="computer">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="epple">Apple</option>
    <option value="remon">Microsoft</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time instead of trying to moderate my question :) Appreciate this!!